# How to create the database with Entity Framework Code First and DDD?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

To implement domain driven design with the Entity Framework I use the approach Julie Lerman presented on TechEd North America 2013 (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B336#fbid=4tnuPF6L-Jc). This approach uses EF entity classes as domain classes. For different bounded contexts domain entity classes have different properties and may even be differently named, although they store their data in the same table. Example is a customer in the "Customer Service" bounded context that is in fact a "Customer", but in the "Shipping" bounded context he is a "Recipient" with only a subset of the customer properties. For each bounded context a different EF context exists that includes only DbSets for the entities the bounded context needs. By overriding OnModelCreating we can even exclude referenced entities that have nothing to do with the bounded context. This part is fairly easy to implement using POCOs.

The problem is the database creation when using Code First. If we let Code First create the database for each different EF context we end up with several databases. If we define the database name in the EF context's constructor the database is created with the first used EF context and we get an InvalidOperationException (saying the model has changed) when the second EF context is used (missing entities, missing properties etc.). We possibly could use migrations to update the database if an EF context is used that uses entities/members other EF contexts before did not have. But that most certainly gets mixed up with the normal use of migrations and will not work properly.
As a temporarily solution I use a separate EF context only for database creation. This means I have to implement all EF entities again just for this purpose. Another problem is that I must create an instance of this EF context on application start to ensure the database gets created and (if necessary) migrated.

I am sure that there are other solutions. So, please (Julie ) tell us how.

Comment: To my mind, bounded countext and EF DBContext aren't the same. Bounded countext is more a logical representation, it's DDD concept while DBContext is EF (implementation). Why not simply have one db - one context and have repository to handle bounded context?

Comment: @StanB: Yes, a bounded context is quite different than a DBContext. Julie Lerman uses a kind of shortcut to avoid that identical classes must be implemented both in the domain model and the Entity Framework model. I really liked this approach although it is not pure DDD. With separated domain classes we would have to implement a double set of classes (in the domain and the EF model) and a mapping between them. One possible solution I currently try out is to return the EF entities as IQueryable in repositories and construct the domain entities from that in the domain services.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't understand the problem. What do you mean by "entity classes as domain classes"? Here is the approach I have gone through with EF/CodeFirst/DDD. Create a separate, persitance ignorant assembly with your domain objects. Define IRepository interface there. Create a separate assembly with EF stuff and implement repositories there. Repository has DBContext, loads and returns domain objects. Use eager loading in the repository to implement your bounded context.

Comment: The layered architecture of DDD defines that layers should only use types in the same layer and in lower layers. A layer should never depend on a higher layer. If an EF context uses domain classes that would be the case, in my opinion. With pure DDD we would need separate domain classes in the domain layer. But let not discuss this further since it does have nothing to do with the basic problem im my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence I believe you will have to have a master context that has all 'tables' defined and also drives migration. This context is what is used to create the database.

All subsequent 'bounded' contexts would have Database.SetInitializer(null) in their constructor to prevent them from tampering with the database schema.

Further both your master context and your 'bounded' contexts should inherit from an abstract base context class that has the connectionstring and such set.

When you application starts you could simply attempt to instantiate your master context and make sure it's migrated to the latest version. But in your actual application later on you only use your 'bounded' contexts that only implements a subset of your master context.

I realize you are already doing some of this in part or whole but I think that is the way to go.

Comment: That's what I thought as well and did so in my projects. Seems to be the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Julie Lermans suggestion. Indded she has been suggesting this approach for sometime.
And you dont need EF6 to do so. Although it can be easier to manage with EF6.

Declare as many Contexts as you like.
The key is the initialization setting of the  Database during context creation.
The basic pattern is as follows

eg

```
// when you wish to migrate
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YOURCONTEXT, YourContentConfiguration>());
var connie = new YOURCONTEXT(.....);

//When you wish to access but NOT change the DB with a small context.
Database.SetInitializer(new ContextInitializerNone<BoundedMiniDbContext>());
var connie = new BoundedMiniDbContext(.....);
```

where yourContent inherits from DbContext and YourContextConfig inherits DbMigrationsConfiguration